# Is there a word for "able to be accumulated"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Sample sentence： Your score "can be accumulated".

I tried 'accumulable', but thought it would be too casual for writing.

Comment: Could you please expand on what you would use word this for that would **ɴᴏᴛ** be better served by the existing adjective *cumulative*? Scores can be cumulative, after all.

Comment: 'Accumulable' is listed by [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/accumulable#:~:text=Definition%20of%20accumulable,%3A%20capable%20of%20being%20accumulated), with no caveats attached. I'd agree it sounds a mouthful, though, and perhaps quirky.

Comment: Perhaps you meant *accumulative*.

Comment: @tchrist "cumulative" is usually a description of how something was calculated, it doesn't describe a capability. So you would say "the score is cumulative".

Comment: Collectable in some cases

Comment: Or "the score carries over", meaning it applies in the succeeding time period as well as the current one.

Comment: This is one of the characteristics of any _fungible_ commodity.

Answer (score -1):

[Amassable](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/amassable): ((Wiktionary) Capable of being amassed.